# Graph Theory : Strongly regular graph

Tags: matrices, graph-theory

A simple graph G which is neither empty nor complete is said to be strongly regular with parameters $(v,k,λ,μ)$ if:

v(G)=v;

G is k-regular;

any two adjacent vertices of G have λ common neighbours,

any two nonadjacent vertices of G have μ common neighbours.

Let G be strongly regular graph with parameters (v,k,λ,μ).show that:

a)$k(k-λ-1)=(v-k-1)μ,$

b)$A^2=kI+λA+μ( J-I-A) $

which A is the adjacency matrix of G, I is the n×n identity matrix and J is the n×n matrix all of whose entries are 1.any help would be great thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Hints. For $a)$ fix a vertex $v$ of a $(v,k, \lambda, \mu)$ SRG  $G$ and double count the number of edges going from vertices in $N(v)$ to $V(G) - N(v) - \{v\}.$

To solve $b)$ recall that if $A$ is the adjacency matrix of a graph $G$ then the entry of $A^k$ at the intersection of the row and column indexing vertices $u,v$ is the number of $k$-walks between $u$ and $v.$